# JAVA - Bad practice to use both JPA and PreparedStatements?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, prepared-statement, datasource

I am writing a java application in which I am using Spring Boot and JPA in order to map classes to my database tables.

However, due to a somewhat complex database structure I also have the need of creating custom queries that are not mapped to any specific POJOs / Entities.

Therefore I am using `PreparedStatement` together with a `DataSource` with `@Autowired` annotation.

It hit me that using both of these DB Access methods might not be suitable to use together?

So far everything has worked out in my dev environment, but are there any pitfalls that I should look out for when using both of these together or is there a preferred way of doing custom queries when using JPA?

It should be noted that my database calls are fairly short and happen in a stateless manner, so there should hopefully not be any problems with interfering sessions (?)

Answer (score 2):

JPA `EntityManager` will not know anything about your changes made with `PreparedStatement`. This will cause issues with JPA built-in caching, maybe with versioning and also with transaction support.

Though you may need to check this question: [Is it OK to use both JPA (for normal CRUDs) and JDBC (for batch update & call stored proc) in the same project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7199950/is-it-ok-to-use-both-jpa-for-normal-cruds-and-jdbc-for-batch-update-call-st)

Comment: I see, that doesn't sound promising unfortunately. Is there any equivalent to `PreparedStatement` be for `EntityManager` since I am in dire need of creating these custom queries that are not mapped to a specific entity...

Answer (score 2):

Invan's answer makes a clear point.

On the other hand your fine when:

- you need complex queries to SHOW data (read only).
- you *infrequently* need to do some batch updates and do a clear cache `entityManager.getEntityManagerFactory().getCache().evictAll()`

Comment: Thank you! The queries are indeed only `SELECT` statements (i.e. no modifying existing data) and serializing the response to json. All writing to the DB is happening by using JPA / Hibernate. Do you think I will be fine using `PreparedStatements` for the select?

Comment: alternatively you could use spring's jdbctemplate

Comment: Why do you want to use SQL when you have JPA? If you use JPA correctly it represents the _object_ model of your domain. If incorrectly, it represents the _data_ model instead. SQL always represents the data model. So which model drives your application? I recommend using the object model. Then you code what makes sense in the object model without worrying about data structures in the database at all.